# Redirect a view page to another view page with arguments in the url

Tags: views, redirection

I have a custom view with button in the main tab placed in the local_task tab bar area (Outcomes). I have sub local_task navigation items under that as well that are regular drupal views. (See below)

View | Edit | **Outcomes** 
                     Outcomes Viewer | **Custom View** | Another Drupal View

When you click on Outcomes you are taken to the Custom View tab or the Default for that custom view. However I want to redirect the Outcomes tab to go to the Outcomes Viewer tab. The Custom View tab is the /default for the menu, so it is s separate link and should work.

However, you can not use /%/ in a redirect. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this. I have tried the basics but am lost on how to make it work.

Thanks!

Comment: While this probably could have been done with some php. I ended up building a small custom module and implement hook_menu() to balance out the buttons path and order.

Answer (score 0):

So, solving this took a few different directions to figure this one out.
The problem was I needed to redirect a view with an argument in the url (node/%/outcomes) to a new sub-button so there was an actual button. (Yes this is also a UX issue that the user needed to have the button)

So, I created a new panel page and in the content area I created new custom content. I used the module, php filter, this way I can use the PHP input for the wysiwyg. Then I pasted this code to redirect.

```
global $base_url;
header("Location: %node/:nid");
```

That redirected and kept the argument so everything would work fine.
Hope that helps someone!